# How to get 0 from subtracting two double numbers?

Tags: c#

For some reason im getting a 2.7234235252E -17 instead of 0 when my program is subtracting .1 - .1, why is that? and how can i properly subtract? and as a third question, if i do subtract .1 - .1, does bool consider it 0? for example: 0 == .1 - .1 = true or false?

```
 List<string> hd1List = new List<string>();



        double hd1CD = 0;
        double hd2CD = 0;
        double hd3CD = 0;
        double hd4CD = 0;


       // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       // {


            if (hd1CD <= 0)
            {

                hd1List.Add("q");

                hd1CD = 4;
                hd1CD = hd1CD - .7;

            }


            Console.WriteLine(hd1CD);
            Console.WriteLine(hd2CD);
            Console.WriteLine(hd3CD);
            Console.WriteLine(hd4CD);


        if (hd2CD <= 0 && hd1CD >= .7)
            {

                hd1List.Add("e");
                hd2CD = 1;
                hd1CD = hd1CD - .7;
                hd2CD = hd2CD - .7;
            }

        Console.WriteLine(hd1CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd2CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd3CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd4CD);

        if (hd3CD <= 0 && hd1CD >= .2 && hd2CD >= .2)
            {
                hd1List.Add("r");
                hd3CD = 5;
                hd1CD = hd1CD - .2;
                hd2CD = hd2CD - .2;
                hd3CD = hd3CD - .2;

            }

        Console.WriteLine(hd1CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd2CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd3CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd4CD);

        if (hd4CD <= 0 && hd1CD >= .1 && hd2CD >= .1 && hd3CD >= .1)
            {
                hd1List.Add("w");
                hd4CD = 3;
                hd1CD = hd1CD - .1;
                hd2CD = hd2CD - .1;
                hd3CD = hd3CD - .1;
                hd4CD = hd4CD - .1;

            }


        Console.WriteLine(hd1CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd2CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd3CD);
        Console.WriteLine(hd4CD);

 if (hd4CD < 1.2 || hd1CD < 1.2 || hd2CD < 1.2 || hd3CD < 1.2 && hd4CD != 0 && hd1CD != 0 && hd2CD != 0 && hd3CD !=0)
The above is checking whether the variables hold 0, since im getting epsilon values my program cant run correctly...
            {
                //get minimum
                hd1List.Add("extra" + superList.Min());

                hd1CD = hd1CD - superList.Min();
                hd2CD = hd2CD - superList.Min();
                hd3CD = hd3CD - superList.Min();
                hd4CD = hd4CD - superList.Min();

            }
```

Summary: how do i re-arrange my code so that if i subtract .1 - .1, it = 0 and not a ridiculous number, i dont need advice, i need an example

Comment: John Skeet has an humorous blog post on this topic: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

Comment: ..or check this post for a more technical description: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have a very good answer I thought I'd have a go at refactoring your code. Have a try of this:

```
List<string> hd1List = new List<string>();
double[] hdCDs = new double[4];
double EPSILON = 0.00000001;

Action<int, double, double, string> update = (i, v, d, t) =>
{
    if (hdCDs[i] <= 0.0 && hdCDs.Take(i).All(x => x >= d))
    {
        hd1List.Add(t);
        hdCDs[i] = v;
        for (int x = 0; x <= i + 1; x++)
        {
            hdCDs[x] =- d;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, hdCDs));
};

update(0, 4.0, 0.7, "q");
update(1, 1.0, 0.7, "e");
update(2, 5.0, 0.2, "r");
update(3, 4.0, 0.1, "w");

if (hdCDs.Any(x => x < 1.2) && hdCDs.All(x => x <= EPSILON))
{
    var min = superList.Min();
    hd1List.Add("extra" + min);
    for (int x = 0; x < hdCDs.Length; x++)
    {
        hdCDs[0] -= min;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not compare double values with `==`. E.g. having code like

`if (value==0) { /* do something here*/ }`

is a bad idea if `value` is a double.

Instead you can do something like:

`if (Math.Abs(value) < EPSILON) { /* do something here*/ }`

where `EPSILON` is some small positive number/constant e.g. `1e-5`.

Comment: I don't see where you compare using `==`. You can rework it yourself.

Comment: oh sorry, updated it , what do i put instead of hd4CD, etc. != 0?

Comment: `Math.Abs(hd4CD) >= EPSILON`